# Changing your host to connect to another port

Tags: http, vagrant, localhost, portforwarding

I am using vagrant and forwarding my 8080 port to my virtual machine.

So for example when I want to open my web app I use `http://example.com:8080`

Now, let's say I want to change my host file to point a specific web to my local host.

Usually what I do is adding the `127.0.0.1 example.com` to my host file.

However, since I use different port I am not sure how to manipulate without forwarding port 80.

Comment: I am not clear here, what do you mean by 'specific web' do you have multiple web site running on the VM ? what is your configuration ...

Comment: It's just theoretical.

Assume I want to make google.com go to 127.0.0.1 but to port 8080 instead of the default 80.

Comment: well in any case you need to have a process listening on this port wether its local or from VM with port forwarding. the host file only manages the IP redirection, then it sends the request on the port you specified and you must have something to handle this request (can be a request proxy or something)